# Given the image, state if point A is a maximum, minimum, saddle point or none of them

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

I am asked the following question:

> The image shows the level curves of an unknown function $f(x,y)$. What can we state about the point A?
>
> a) It´s a maximum
>
> b) It´s a minimum
>
> c) It´s a saddle point
>
> d) None of the above

[image]

Im prone to saying **none of the above** sine, for me, it looks like a discontinuity of the function (as if it were increasing up until infinity.

Is my reasoning correct?

**EDIT:** This actually **is** from a book. If the question is not well-made, I want to have arguments to contact the writer, so I am very interested to know if thats the case.

Comment: Why not decreasing? And why infinity? Is there a reason why $f(A)$ cannot be finite?

Comment: @Did So the function is "obviously" not $(x^2-y^2)^2$? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x%5E2-y%5E2)%5E2

Comment: (or to better align with the orientation of the plot in the OP, $\left((x+y)^2 + (x-y)^2\right)^2$)

Comment: @user7530 Right.

Comment: @Did Why not? Unless I'm missing something the level sets look more or less identical to those in the OP?

Comment: @user7530 maybe you mistyped the equation but the level curves do not look like the ones in the question

Comment: Yes I missed a minus sign. Here it is: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x%2By%29%5E2+-+%28x-y%29%5E2%29%5E2

Comment: If you cube instead you get a saddle point: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x%2By%29%5E2+-+%28x-y%29%5E2%29%5E3.

Comment: @user7530 "Why not?" Why not what? Please see my previous message.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safe to assume that the function is continuous (since plotting level sets can't tell you much of anything about a function that isn't continuous), but even so, without knowing the values of the function on the level sets in the figure, you can't say anything, except that the point is a (perhaps non-isolated) critical point. It's a good exercise to think of function values on the level sets for which each of those answers is the correct one.

Comment: I see. It seems like a very poor-built question, right?

Comment: @bru1987 right.